# After form submitting I don't get multiple values in array

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

When I click `Add More` Button then appending the same row and when I submit the form then I getting the first value of the `product_name` and `color_id` input field.Where is the problem I didn't  find that.

**Here is the html code:**

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered text-center table-responsive">
<thead class="text-dark">
    <tr>
        <th>Product Name</th>
        <th>Color</th>
        @foreach($size_infos as $sizee)
        <th>{{$sizee->size_name}}</th>
        @endforeach
        <th>Add More</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<form action={{url('product-purchase-process')}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    <tbody class="add_item">
        <tr>
            <td width="20%">
                <input class="form-control input typeahead" type="text" name="product_name[]" id="product_name" placeholder="Product Name" multiple='multiple'>
            </td>
            <td width="14%">
                <select class="form-control input" name="color_id[]">
                    <option value="">--Select Color--</option>
                    @foreach($color_infos as $color)
                    <option value="{{$color->color_id}}">{{$color->color_name}}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </td>
            @foreach($size_infos as $size)
            <td>
                <div id="inputDiv">
                    <input type="hidden" name="size_id[]" value="{{$size->size_id}}" multiple='multiple'>
                    <input style="width:70px" class="from-control" type="text" name="product_quantity[]" multiple='multiple'>
                </div>
            </td>
            @endforeach
            <td width="10%">
                <button type="button" id="add_more" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

**Here is the jquery code:**

```
<script type = "text/javascript" >
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

$(document).on('focus', "#product_name", function () {
    $(this).autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "{{url('autocomplete')}}",
                data: {
                    products: request.products
                },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    var resp = $.map(data, function (obj) {
                        // console.log(obj.product_name);
                        return obj.product_name;
                    });
                    response(resp);
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 1
    });
    //color field and image field extend here
    var htmlString = `<tr class="ree"><td width="20%"><input class="form-control input typeahead" type="text" name="product_name[]" id="product_name" placeholder="Product Name"></td><td width="14%"><select class="form-control input" name="color_id"><option value="">--Select Color--</option>@foreach($color_infos as $colorr)<option value="{{$colorr->color_id}}">{{$colorr->color_name}}</option>@endforeach</select></td>@foreach($size_infos as $sizeee)<td><div id="inputDiv"><input type="hidden" name="size_id[]" value="{{$sizeee->size_id}}"><input style="width:70px" class="from-control" type="text" name="product_quantity[]"></div></td>@endforeach<td width="10%"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btnRemove"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></td></tr>`;
    $('#add_more').click(function () {
        $('.add_item').append(htmlString); // end append
        $('.ree .btnRemove').last().click(function () {
            $(this).parent().last().remove();
        }); // end click
    }); // end click

}); </script>
```

Comment: You can not nest a form into a table like this - it either needs to be contained completely in a single table cell, or put around the whole table. The invalid HTML you created here makes the browser apply error correction by closing the form again before the tbody, so all the form fields are not really part of the form.

Comment: Thanks, I realized the mistake of my code.